# Classifying space induces a equivalence of categories between $\operatorname{PBun}_G(M)$ and $\Pi(M,BG)$ for finite groups $G$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, finite-groups, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces, groupoids

Let $G$ be a finite group, $BG$ its classifying space and M a manifold. Then it is mentioned in [Schweigert and Woike - Orbifold construction for topological field theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05171) (Remark 2.3 d) that there is an equivalence of categories
$$
\Pi (M,BG) \cong \operatorname{PBun}_G(M)
$$
between the groupoid of maps from $M$ to $BG$ (with homotopy classes of homotopies as morphisms) and the groupoid of principal $G$-bundles over $M$. **How can one prove that? Where in the literature can I find a proof of that?**

I could only find proofs that homotopy classes of maps correspond to isomorphism classes of principal bundles. But in order to prove that it gives an equivalence of categories I also need that the morphisms correspond to each other.

That they correspond to each other is also mentioned in [Heinloth - Some notes on differentiable stacks](https://www.uni-due.de/%7Ehm0002/stacks.pdf) (in the beginning of chapter 1), but no proof is given.

I already asked this questions on https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3954305/864293 and I was recommended to ask the question here.

Comment: I've answered the question on stack.exchange.